# Website Console Javascript > getElementsByName> Need defaultValue attribute returned

Tags: javascript, servicenow, rpa, automationanywhere

I am trying to get a unique identifier out of a ServiceNow webpage source code.  I have identified where it is and I was hoping someone could help me to return the value that I need.

[image]

Here is an image of the attribute I would like returned.... any help would be appreciated.  I am not familiar with JS so please forgive me if my terminology is not correct.

Then end goal is to take a baseURL and then add this string as a parameter to get the RPA software I am using to navigate to this page.

baseURL + defaultValue

I have tried many different combinations of document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll

I am unfamiliar with js syntax so this is an uphill battle for me.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, this can help you finding what you need:

```
let myElement = document.getElementByName("sys_original.x_eyit2_dsr_dsr_task.dsr_case")

let myDesiredValue = myElement[0].defaultValue

console.log(myDesiredValue)
```

What you are looking for is probably a JSON Object. I said "probably", because we don't have more details about your question.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful in getting me to the resolution.  I was not aware that the nodes can be referenced as you have mentioned above.  I really appreciate the assistance.